# (PHP) Long list of undefined Variables.

Tags: php

I know that this will be marked as a duplicate, but I have went through most of the other questions on undefined variables, but unfortunately I havn't had any joy. I am brand new to PHP, and web design in general.

My PHP code:

```
 <?php
    include('connection.php');
    $getid = $_GET['getid'];

    if (isset($_POST['userID'])) {
        $userID = $_POST['userID'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])) {
        $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['accessLevel'])) {
        $accesslevel = $_POST['accessLevel'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }



    $update = "UPDATE users SET userID='$userID', 
    emailAddress='$emailAddress', 
   firstName='$firstName', lastName='$lastName',accessLevel = 
   '$accesslevel',password='$password' WHERE userID = '$getid'";

     $return = mysqli_query($conn, $update) or die(mysqli_errno($conn));
```

I keep getting this message(s):

```
Notice: Undefined variable: userID in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: emailAddress in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: firstName in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: lastName in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: accesslevel in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: password in /var/www/vhosts/rdonaghy08.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/httpdocs/cater/updatedProfile.php on line 28
```

My exact question is, why are they coming up as undefined since I have, seemingly, defined them with the $_isset($_POST) declarations in my IF statements? Have I not defined them?

Thanks in advance for any help or clarification provided!

Comment: it may be that you are not connected to database.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: These variables are only set if the corresponding $_POST value is set.  So you need to find out what post values are sent and only do the UPDATE if the required ones are there.

Comment: Not sure about the idea that the form can update every part of the record (including the ID).  Also you have to be careful that if you don't provide all of the data, then it may clear the data already on the database.  Lastly is to say that storing plain passwords is not a good idea.

Comment: SQL injections with unhashed passwords is going to lead you to huge problems. Also in what instance would a user ever need to change their `userID`?

Comment: @Chris to be able to access others accounts :-)

Comment: Be sure you whatever is between your POST match your `<input name="name">` `$_POST['name']`

Answer (score 3):

You check if the variable is set yes, but if it's not set you don't do anything about it.
Then at the line with $update you still use the possibly unset variables.

You could do:

```
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}else{
    $error = true;
}
```

And the same on each of the isset lines.
Then you check if error is true before going on with the rest of the code.

```
if(!$error){
    $update = "UPDATE users SET userID='$userID', 
emailAddress='$emailAddress',firstName='$firstName', lastName='$lastName'accessLevel ='$accesslevel',password='$password' WHERE userID = '$getid'";

     $return = mysqli_query($conn, $update) or die(mysqli_errno($conn));
}
```

This way the two lines above is only entered if there is no error.